# Pattern for returning specific error information or successful validation of an object

Tags: java, design-patterns, error-handling

We have a combination of number where the first to numbers determine a format for the last one:

```
0001/0001/AF001 -> 0001/0001 == Rule for third number: two characters, three digits
0002/0001/0001 -> 0002/0001 == Rule for third number: four digits
```

We need to validate these numbers before storing them in a database. Since this is a common problem in several of our projects, we want to do the validation in a central service (in this case a ejb).

My first idea was to just use a method like:

```
public boolean isValid(String number1, String number2, String number3);
```

but we want to relay the rule if something is not valid, so that the user can see what went wrong, so my next idea is:

```
public void checkNumbers(String number1, String number2, String number3) throws DetailsException;
```

So one could invoke that like this:

```
try {
  checkNumbers("0001", "0001", "AF002");
} catch(DetailsException d) {
  // error handling
}
```

But this seems kind of ugly... What are the alternives/other ideas to solve this situation. Is there a typical pattern to use?

Comment: How is exception handling ugly, especially with no nested exceptions?

Comment: Mhm,... it's just a feeling. Maybe because I did a little functional programming in the past few days... and not returning something feels weird. And then there is the notions not to use Exception handling for flow control (I think that's mentioned in Effective Java?!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, a customary (but somewhat old-fashioned) alternative to throwing an exception is returning an error code (or error object):

```
ErrorInfo err = checkNumbers(n1, n2, n3);
if (err != null)
{
    ...
```

But I personally would go for the variant with exception.

Comment: I'd second the exception variant.